# Gradle (tomcat-plugin): tomcatRun cannot execute GWT JS

Tags: gwt, web-applications, deployment, gradle, tomcat7

I am trying to build a GWT enabled web application with Gradle (on Ubuntu Linux).

I have configured everything, and Gradle manages to successfully build the application, but when I run the task "tomcatRun", I can only see a blank page, which is a result of GWT javascript not executing (if I view the page source, it is there). No errors, no warnings from Tomcat, just that blank page.

However, when I run "tomcatRunWar", everything works perfectly. I can't figure out what might be wrong or why might this happen.

This is my `gradle.build` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.0"
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  /* Tomcat plugin dependencies */
  def tomcatVersion = '7.0.47'
  tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
  tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
  }

  /* Google Web Toolkit */
  def gwtVersion = '2.5.1'
  providedCompile "com.google.gwt:gwt-user:${gwtVersion}"
  providedCompile "com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:${gwtVersion}"
  runtime "com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:${gwtVersion}"

  /* Spring Security */
  def springVersion = '3.1.4.RELEASE'
  compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springVersion}"
  compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springVersion}"
}

/* Task to compile the client package GWT code to JavaScript */
task gwtCompile (dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
  buildDir = "${project.buildDir}/gwt"
  extraDir = "${project.buildDir}/extra"

  inputs.source sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  inputs.dir sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
  outputs.dir buildDir

  doFirst {
    file(buildDir).mkdirs()
  }

  main = "com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"

  classpath {
    [
      sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,         // Java source
      sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir,  // Generated resources
      sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,    // Generated classes
      sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,     // Dependencies
    ]
  }

  args = [
    '<package_path_to_GWT_module>',        // Our GWT module
    '-war', buildDir,
    '-logLevel', 'INFO',
    '-localWorkers', '2',
    '-compileReport',
    '-extra', extraDir,
  ]

  maxHeapSize = '256M'

}

/* Make the war plugin depend on the gwtCompile task */
war.dependsOn gwtCompile
/* Include the contents of the GWT compilation in the generated WAR file */
war {
  from gwtCompile.buildDir
}

/* Configure the eclipse plugin in case it is used */
eclipse {
  project {
    natures 'com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature'
    buildCommand 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator'
    buildCommand 'com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator'
  }

  classpath {
    containers 'com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER'
  }
}
```

My directory tree looks like this:

```
ProjectHome
-- src
   -- main
     -- java
        -- <packages>
     -- webapp
        -- WEB-INF
           -- web.xml
        -- index.html
   -- test
-- build.gradle
```

I have also compared the resulting WAR's directory tree with the one used by the 'tomcatRun' task (build/libs/ProjectName) and they seem identical.

Does anyone have any ideas for this?

// **Edit:** Actually, it does not display an empty page, it just can't execute the GWT Javascript, to assign content to the only div in body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution.

You actually have to copy the needed files into the src/main/webapp directory (or make the build script do that or even better configure the tomcat-plugin to read the files from elsewhere - if that is possible), because tomcatRun reads the files from there. I was expecting it to read them from where the WAR file lies in (build/libs), but this is not the case.

So, the best option here, given that the GWT plugin is still a work in progress, is to use the tomcatRunWar option.

Comment: The task `tomcatRun` does not bundle a WAR file beforehand. It uses the source directory conventions provided by the Java and War plugin to resolve files.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, is there any way to modify the build script to tell the tomcat plugin to use the location of built files instead?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: My gradle script builds the files to the Project/build directory. Is there any way to make tomcatRun use that folder as the ROOT webapp directory?

Comment: I think I still can't follow you yet. Are you talking about files produced by GWT? Do you have the code on GitHub or somewhere else?

Comment: No I don't. It is just a sample project I use to try Gradle out. The thing is that Gradle "produces" the index.html, WEB-INF folder, etc. in a folder called /build/libs, under the project folder, instead of the /src/main/webapp folder which tomcatRun uses as the ROOT webapp folder. I might be messing something up really badly though.

Comment: Correct. The War plugin only allows you to set a single web application source folder. Your best bet is to use the `tomcatRunWar` task which actually assembles the WAR first. You might want to have a look at the Gradle GWT plugin. I am not sure if that will be of any help as I haven't used it.